# block level backup of zfs storage pool

Tags: zfs, volumes

Is possible to take a backup of zfs storage pool ? 
If the FS is on a raw disk, we can open and read the character device interface  to replicate the disk to a file.We can mount the file using the loop device interface. Is it possible to do this in zpool programatically using open, read system calls?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend looking into the ZFS replication feature, which uses the `send` and `receive` subcommands.  With those tools, you can generate a block-level data stream of a particular dataset and save that stream to a file.  If you generate a stream for the root dataset and include all child datasets, that will capture all data in the pool.  Note that `zfs send` operates on a snapshot, so you will need to take a recursive snapshot beforehand:

```
zfs snapshot -r tank@current
zfs send -R tank@current > ./stream.zfs
```

Then when you want to restore your data:

```
cat ./stream.zfs | zfs receive tank
```